# Is Laravel File Uploading Secure if considered only image

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-4

Laravel basically have following below functions for `input` type `file`.

```
// Determine if a file was uploaded
 Input::hasFile('filename');
// Access file properties
 Input::file('name')->getRealPath();
Input::file('name')->getClientOriginalName();
Input::file('name')->getClientOriginalExtension();
Input::file('name')->getSize();
Input::file('name')->getMimeType();
```

If i use `getClientOriginalExtension` to find correct image extension, `getSize` to restrict file upload size & `getMimeType` to check the mimetype of image.

Am i secured ? And can have faith on function that , it will not be exploited by hacker in any way.

Considering a fact, that i will be only uploading image.

---

### Update : Follow below URL for File Uploading Securely with Core PHP :

**http://php.w3clan.com/tutorial/47/form-handling-secure-uploading**

### or Just use file validation in rule as per Laravel

`$rule = [ 'name' => 'image'  ];`

Comment: You can use the image validator rule aswell. `$rules = [ 'file' => 'image' ]`

Comment: Yes, Will all those above makes it completely secure enough ?

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635207/php-fileupload-type-check/27636611#27636611

Comment: If you only intend to upload images, you don't need `getMimeType` to check for the mime type as far as I'm aware since the `image` rule in the validator checks for mime types image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif and others. If you further want to whitelist to for example only jpg and png, you can check for the extension aswell. Although only checking for the extension can let people upload any file they wish if they change the extension. I could upload an executable which is named *definitely-not-an-exe-file.png* and still be able to upload it.

Comment: You could try security check by the combination of  `getClientMimeType()` and `getClientOriginalExtension()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems pretty secure to me.

If you only intend to upload images, you can do this:

```
$rules [
    ...
    'file' => 'required|image' // Assuming it's required, otherwise leave that out
]
```

See [the image validation rule](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-image)

If you want to further restrict which extensions are allowed, you can specify an array with the extensions you allow, and then check `Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension()` against it. Although this can be spoofed, so it's better to specify which mime types are allowed instead.

If you for example only want to allow .png and .gif files, you use:

```
$allowedMimes = [
    'image/gif',
    'image/png'
];
```

And then check using `->getMimeType()`

Comment: u can add '|mime:png,gif' to the validation rules http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-mimes ,but note the mime-type differs from a browser to another specially (IE & FF)