# php - How to make file uploaded only image - Laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel, photo

Hello im newbie in laravel so i really need some help. I want to create a code where only the image that can upload other files can not, I have tried to use the code input file but when I try to upload the zip file file it still uploaded so I really need help

This is my table code

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
{!! Form::label('photo', 'Photo:') !!}
<input type='file' name='photo' class='form-control' accept = 'image/jpeg , image/jpg, image/gif, image/png'>
```

And this is my Controller

```
    public function store(CreateBannerRequest $request)
{

    $input = $request->all();
    //get original file name
    if($request->photo == NULL)
    {
        Flash::error('Image must be filled');
        return back();
    }
    $filename = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
    $input['photo'] =  $filename;
     $banner = $this->BannerRepository->create($input);
    //upload file
    Input::file('photo')->move($this->path, $filename); 

     Flash::success('Banner saved successfully.');

     if (empty($banner)) {
        Flash::error('No image available');

        return redirect(route('banner.index'));
    }

     return redirect(route('banner.index'));
}
```

[image: This is the view of my code]

Comment: Hey, are you there, You need to validation file type at the backend and just file upload field with name in frontend.

Comment: @SagarGautam Can you show me the code please :D

Comment: I'll add in answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have code at front end like this:

**View**

```
<form action="{{URL::to('upload/photo')}}" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="photo">
    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('upload/photo','TestController@uploadPhoto');
```

**TestController**

```
public function uploadPhoto(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'photo' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,bmp,tiff |max:4096',
    ],
        $messages = [
            'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
            'mimes' => 'Only jpeg, png, bmp,tiff are allowed.'
        ]
    );
 // Now save your file to the storage and file details at database.
}
```

I hope, you undestand.

Comment: Thanks for help :D but is that mean i need to make new route and public function?

Comment: @SahatRiyanto I've added whole way so that you can easily understand. You can add these code as required on your existing function

Comment: Thank you so much its really worked :D god bless you

Comment: @SahatRiyanto I'm happy that it helped you, Congrats.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with validation throuhg `mimes:jpeg` and the other types such as png etc. lookup laravel validation on the documentation page

Comment: Thanks for response, but i have tried and still didnt work maybe you can show me the code because im really newbie in Laravel :D
And this is the reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646204/is-laravel-file-uploading-secure-if-considered-only-image

Comment: so in the `CreateBannerRequest` under the rules `public function rules()
{
    return [
        'photo' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
    ];
}
` heres a gotcha you need to be under 5.3 or later i believe the versions before have some issues there.

Comment: Thanks but it still didnt work https://imgur.com/a/t9OKg I have tried your code but when i try upload zip file its still uploaded :D

Comment: @SahatRiyanto you can try the answer I've added